# Factory design pattern implementation?

Tags: python, factory, factory-pattern

i have been looking into implementing factory method design pattern in python & most examples that I get is something of this form.

```
class Cup:
    color = ""

    # This is the factory method
    @staticmethod
    def getCup(cupColor):
        if (cupColor == "red"):
            return RedCup()
        elif (cupColor == "blue"):
            return BlueCup()
        else:
            return None

class RedCup(Cup):
    color = "red"

class BlueCup(Cup):
    color = "blue"

# A little testing
redCup = Cup.getCup("red")
print "%s(%s)" % (redCup.color, redCup.__class__.__name__)

blueCup = Cup.getCup("blue")
print "%s(%s)" % (blueCup.color, blueCup.__class__.__name__)
```

Why use `class` for a factory function?

Couldn't it just be like this:

```
def CupFactory(cupColor):
    if (cupColor == "red"):
        return RedCup()
    elif (cupColor == "blue"):
        return BlueCup()
    else:
        return None
```

or there is a particular situation where the class-based method is prefered/desired.

**NOTE :** Examples found on internet that use classes.

[Example 1](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html).
 [Example 2](https://pythonspot.com/factory-method/)

Comment: @Aran-Fey , the question you linked seems similar but it is not. the suggested solution is to use alternate constructor by using `@classmethod` that is one way to create factories but i have entirely different question, `why would one ever use a class for a factory?` , using `altrnate constructors/@staticmethod` is not suitable in this case i guess

Comment: You're saying the *only* purpose of the `Cup` class is to hold the factory method?

Comment: yes, this is what i am confused as most examples show something similar(i have even mentioned a link in my question). according to me using a class here is an overkill and a simple function would be enough.but are there any cases in which i might need a class to create a factory?

Comment: Ok, I've reopened the question.

Comment: Given the `camelCase` method names, I suspect you have the very common case of someone writing Java in Python.... but more seriously, these are probably just simple examples. A class factory object may require more complicated methods.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga more complicated methods like?